# Meaning of "the shadows were about their own business”

Tags: meaning, literature

‎What does “shadows” from the novel, [Six of Crows](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Six_of_Crows/uqUwCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Her%20father%20would%20have%20said%20the%20shadows%20were%20about%20their%20own%20business%22&pg=PT28&printsec=frontcover), mean here?

> Her father would have said the shadows were about their own business tonight.

Does it mean people who follow someone? I need help.

Comment: The quote needs context. We need to know whose shadows they are. If the shadows are metaphorical. If the daughter is a small child or an adult. If this is a scary story. AND you need to look up the term *shadows*, include its definition in the question along with the source and explain to us in more detail why the term is confusing you. EDIT OK, we have the title of the story. A link, if possible would be nice.

Comment: For asking questions about the meaning of particular words **in the context of a story**, rather than just their meaning in English generally, you may also consider [literature.se].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a Q of interpretation, not meaning

Answer (score 1):

"shadows" is similar to *ghosts* in this context, as mentioned [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_person), a "Shadow Person" is:

> the perception of a patch of shadow as a living, humanoid figure, and interpreted as the presence of a spirit or other entity by believers in the paranormal or supernatural.

The sentence literally means:

> Her father would have said the **paranormal spirits** were about their own business tonight.